# Create variable from excel file

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file with what I would like to become variables in column 1 and values in column 2:

```
Plot.Shift            20
Plot.MarkerSize       6
Plot.MarkerColor      black
Plot.MarkerFaceColor  black
Plot.FontSize         22
```

I read the file with

```
s=readcell('PlotOptions.xlsx','Sheet','PlotOptions');
```

I would like to have new variable, **Plot** in the MATLAB code such as:

```
>> Plot.Shift % Set it to 20
>> Plot.MarkerSize % Set to 6
```

Comment: I don't understand why don't you use @UnbearableLightness answer's. It does exactly what you're asking. Even `Plot.Shift+Plot.Shift
ans =
    40`

Answer (score 1):

Using [cell2struct](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html):

```
s=readcell('PlotOptions.xlsx','Sheet','PlotOptions');
field_names=regexp(s(:,1),'(?<=\.)[A-Za-z]+$','match','once');
Plot = cell2struct(s,field_names);
Plot(1) = [];
```

`Plot` is a struct with the desired fields:

```
>> Plot.Shift
20

>> Plot.MarkerFaceSize
6

...
```

Comment: Almost, but I can not make an operation such as Plot.Shift +Plot.SHift, and plot does not recognize the field Plot.MarkerFaceColor

Comment: Because the `plot` command needs the `MarkerFaceColor` in a format it knows. For the color black the parameter `MarkerFaceColor` can be either the string `'k'`, or the RGB value `[1 1 1]`. I don't think it recognize the string `black`.

Comment: @Hoki Yeah of course, but that's never mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ha ha, sorry for the confusion. My comment was for @user2260180, to explain why the disfunction he mention had nothing to do with the solution you proposed but rather with the initial set of options he defined.

Comment: Well, never mind if the color is specified as 'black' or simply 'k', the point is that a) I can not operate on the retrieved variables: i.eK>> Plot.Shift+Plot.Shift
Error using  + 
Too many input arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `cell2struct` to convert your heterogeneous data from into a struct array.

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html), sturcts allow you to refer to each item through the requested dot notation while maintaining support for heterogeneous data types.

```
structArray = cell2struct(cellArray, fields, dim)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not get it, can you provide the matlab code associated with my code?